# Promise.all Showing data in loop console but not passing data to state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having problem with Promise.all function for multiple API calls. I am making multiple api calls and then console.log the result. I am able to see the results when do `console.log` within the `map` function, but when trying to set the state in order to render and display in UI, the data is not flowing to state. I don't know where exactly the problem is and why data is not flowing to state.

Here is my code.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        
        const promises = data.map(id => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              fetch(`https://example.com/api/ITems/${id.ID}`)
                .then(response => {
                  return new Promise(() => {
                    response.json()
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response); // this console log is showing me data into console, but the console.log below in promise.all section is not showing any data
                        resolve()
                      })
                      .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                  })
                })
            })
          })

        Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
            this.setState({Ids: results.data}); // no data is passing to state
           console.log(results); // this console.log does not work. when remove the console.log in loop, i cannot see anything. data is not flowing here
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
      }
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are either of the `console.log(error);`s logging something?

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance . No error in console.

Comment: `Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
            this.setState({Ids: results.data});
           console.log(results);
        }) ` data is not coming here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because you are resolving as undefined thus all of your promises return value is `undefined`

Change it to: `resolve(response)` and that way it will actually resolve using your desired `response`

```
    const promises = data.map(id => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          fetch(`https://example.com/api/ITems/${id.ID}?realm=xyz`, { headers })
            .then(response => {
              return new Promise(() => {
                return response.json() // <--------------------------- Additionally you need to return this as well
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response); // this console log is showing me data into console, but the console.log below in promise.all section is not showing any data
                    resolve(response) // <---------------------------- ISSUE is here
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
              })
            })
        })
      })
```

Comment: Hi @Rikin. You are right. The array in promise.all section was undefined in console. now data is coming . that console is working. But still have a challenge. Data is still not in state.  Promise.all(promises)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({Ids: response.data}); // still no data
           console.log(response); // this is working . showing data in console
        })

Comment: constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Ids: []
        };
       console.log(this.state.Ids); // no data still here
    }

Comment: @Raza I guess you just need to look at the shape of the object in your console.log and adjust accordingly. May be its `response.data.data`? I cant tell without the shape of how its being logged in console. If you are not sure try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))` and let me know and I'll point you to it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rikin . its working now. the last issue was due to `this.setState({Ids: response.data});` I was concatenating the .data with response. Much Appricated and thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You're not `resolve`ing with anything. Consider avoiding the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), and `.catch` only in the `Promise.all`:

```
const promises = data.map(id => 
  fetch(`https://example.com/api/ITems/${id.ID}?realm=xyz`, { headers })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => result.data)
 );
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  this.setState({Ids: results});
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The value `Promise.all` gets resolved with will always be an *array* - it won't have a `.data` property. It sounds like each individual `fetch` result returns an object with a `data` property, so you should do that inside the `.map` as done above, not in the `Promise.all`.

Comment: Thanks alot @CertainPerformance. Really appreciated. It was really helpful.